# React Native: How to save date in realm DB

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

My realm model is:

```
const itemsSchema = {
    name: 'items',
    properties: {
        key: 'int',
        business_id: 'int',
        item_id: 'int',
        item_name: 'string',
        item_price: 'float',
        datetime: 'date'
        // datetime: 'string'
    }
};
```

I want to save the current date every time user hits a save button and this is the code executed on save which saves the data if I make my model property `datetime: 'string'`

```
realm.write(() => {
    realm.create('items', {
        key: 0,
        business_id: QRData.business_id,
        item_id: QRData.item_id,
        item_name: QRData.item_name,
        item_price: QRData.item_price,
        datetime: new Date('2017-06-06 21:23:53')
    });
});
```

But if try to save it with model property set as **date** it throws this error:

**Error: Value 'Invalid Date' not convertible to a number.**

Comment: It seems the date of 2017-06-06 21:23:53 is not a valid format.

Comment: @LajosArpad What is a valid format?

Comment: Depends on your server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
new Date('2017-06-06 21:23:53')
```

you can instantiate Date with parameters, like

```
new Date(2017, 6, 6, 21, 23, 53)
```

Note that month starts from 0.

Comment: Should I wrap the params in quotes ' ?

Comment: @Omer you don't need to. Just test this instantiation and if works, then accept my answer. If not, then please give me information about the problem you see.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date('2017-06-06 21:23:53')` is an invalid format.

Try `new Date('2017-06-06T21:23:53')`

It works for me.